# Eclipse permanently not responding while debugging

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging, wildfly, no-response

I was wondering if anyone has experienced this problem.

We work with Eclipse 2020-03 running Wildfly 16 and OpenJDK 1.12 on a Windows 10 Desktop connecting the a local instance of SQL Server. When the app server is deployed we connect using Chrome or IE. When I'm debugging the java app, Eclipse becomes unresponsive. It could go 2 or 3 days before this happens and then happen 10 times back to back. It is inconsistent and I cannot determine what I might being doing to cause the issue. I have worked with older versions of Eclipse and have not had this issue till the Luna version. Of course at the same time we moved to Maven and GIT as well. 

Some of symptoms
1. Hang when stepping through code.
2. Hang when click away after stopped at a breakpoint and then coming back.
3. Hang when inspecting variables.
4. Hang when increase the display area of one of the variables when its a long String.

If I just run and do not interact with the debug perspective, I have no issue and it never hangs.

Funny thing is we have at least a hundred developers running with this setup and only 2 or 3 of us have had this problem. At least from what I have tried to gather in terms of information.

Things I've tried
1. Complete format and re-install of PC. (I was desparate)
2. Upgraded Eclipse from 2019-03.
3. Based on google searches, turned off mylyn
4. Logged a comment on a issue with Eclipse: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=322126
5. Reviewed Eclipse, Wildfly and Java logs. Nothing of note.
6. Changes startup parameters of Eclipse with no luck.
7. A few other things I cannot remember.

To recover, I have to terminate the Eclipse process and the terminate the OpenJDK process.

Any help would be appreciated.